# fullCalendar event source takes too long to load

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, fullcalendar

I am using fullCalendar with jQuery/PHP/mySQL to show a calendar scheduler.  On my localhost machine test server, it works pretty fast.

Now that I am trying to make my site live, I am testing things out on my server.

I notice that the ajax call that gets the events for fullCalendar takes very long to load (>15 seconds!).  I have thousands of events that are gathered on the ajax page.

```
 var calendar = $("#calendar_full").fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            editable: true,
            slotDuration: '00:10:00',
            minTime: "<?php echo $location->data()->calendar_start; ?>",
            maxTime: "<?php echo $location->data()->calendar_end; ?>",
            hiddenDays: $.parseJSON('[' + "<?php echo $location->data()->calendar_hide_days_of_week; ?>" + ']'),
            defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
            eventLimit: true,
            events: 'ajax_get_json.php?what=company_all_appointments',
            eventRender: function eventRender(event, element, view) {

                return ['all', event.location_id].indexOf($('#calendar_location_id option:selected').val()) >= 0 && ['all', event.saw_by_id].indexOf($('#calendar_provider_id option:selected').val()) >= 0;

            }, ...
 ...
```

On the ajax page, the following query is run on my server:

```
 SELECT post_notes, post_appt_statuses.`status` AS post_appt_status_name, post_appt_status_id, CONCAT_WS(' ', users.first_name, users.last_name) AS scheduled_with_name, appt_reasons.reason AS appt_reason_name, appt_statuses.status AS appt_status_name, appts.date_created, appts.inserted_by_user_id, appts.saw_by_id, appts.company_id, appts.location_id, locations.name AS location_name, marketing_events.promo_code, appt_status_id, howheard_id, appts.marketing_event_id, appts.allDay, reason_id, appts.pre_notes, appt_reasons.color, appt_reasons.textColor, contacts.id AS appt_contact_id, contacts.friends_call_me, contacts.first_name, contacts.last_name, appts.id, appts.start, appts.end 
 FROM appointments appts 
 LEFT JOIN marketing_events ON marketing_events.id = appts.marketing_event_id LEFT JOIN locations ON locations.ID = appts.location_id 
 LEFT JOIN appt_reasons ON appt_reasons.id = appts.reason_id 
 LEFT JOIN contacts ON contacts.id = appts.contact_id 
 LEFT JOIN appt_statuses ON appt_statuses.id = appts.appt_status_id     
 LEFT JOIN post_appt_statuses ON post_appt_statuses.id = appts.post_appt_status_id 
 LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = appts.saw_by_id  WHERE appts.company_id = '" . $company . "'
```

I know it's a big select statement and the many JOINS slow down the query, but I DO need all the info from the JOINS for a modal form which shows when an event in the calendar is selected.

Is there a good way to make the events load faster from the ajax call?

Comment: Indexes. Indexes. Indexes. Indexes. And, also important, indexes. If you have them, you should add the `explain` output so we can check if they work as expected. Apart from that, you could, depending on how you use the calendar, restrict your query to the results you actually need, because it would expect it is very unlikely anyone will look at all 1000 events in detail. So e.g. fetch exactly the one you display in the modal form, or fetch just the current month, and load the details from 2 years ago only when the user goes there.

Comment: As @Solarflare mentioned, only fetching data for those in range would probably be a good starting point. fullcalendar passed **start** and **end** parameters to the events url you can use to restrict the events to those that fall within the current view. As a side note, the SQL you are using **appts.company_id = '" . $company . "'** could lead to sql injection

Comment: So this has been great. Thanks for taking the time to give me feedback.  I have added the start and end date parameters to my query.  It has dramatically improved the speed of the ajax return.  I need to learn more about indexes, but, you're right, I've been told start using them.  Thirdly, I will escape my $company variable properly to avoid injection. Thanks again.